# which scheduled job handles email confirmations?

Tags: email, groups, cron-job

When contacts add themselves to a mailing list group, they get a confirmation mail, saying

> You have a pending subscription to the [xxxx] Mailing
>   list. To confirm this subscription, reply to this email or click here.

The click works, the reply doesnt. It gets send to an email address that is otherwise set up correctly to handle mailing bounces (its an address like  [foo]+c.3.3.cde2e639840a9457@[mydomain] )

Which scheduled job should I enable to pick up this confirmation ?

Answer (score 1):

The bounce processor is in general the one handling, well, the bounces. Check the job log if something is written (but in general, the jobs aren't very good at returning the problems they encounter)

How often is your bounce processor running?